# E: The package tzdata needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I need to re-install this to upgrade 11.04 Ubuntu to 11.10

I keep getting an error when I try:

```
sudo apt-get install tzdata


E: The package tzdata needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: try sudo apt-get update, then running the command

Comment: I get -->  W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: there's something wrong with your repository server - you might want to try switching them, maybe with synaptic

Answer (score 0):

As Journeyman Geek commented, if changing what repos you are pulling from, running apt-get update and retrying doesn't work then try manually downloading the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com and installing via dpkg -i.

You still need to resolve the repo errors to be able to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

In a Dockerfile, you would install

```
sudo echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
```

*before* the first apt-get. And then, whatever you like, for example:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get -y \
--no-install-recommends install ...
```

See [How to install tzdata on a ubuntu docker image?](https://serverfault.com/a/1088129/607547) for details.